# Add Novel Groupwise Account via Exchange ActiveSync to Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange-activesync

I want to add my Novel GroupWise account to my Mac, which is not possible due to the lack of a (reliable and recent) client. The firm I'm working for set a data sync server up for this purpose but that only supports Exchange Active Sync if I am understanding it correctly.

I am assuming this because setting up the account as an exchange account on the iPhone and iPad was no problem but it does not work in mail.

Does there exist a workaround for this situation? Maybe some daemon that pretends to be an mobile client and fetches everything? I would really like to be able to add the work calendar and emails on my mac. I'm running the latest El Capitan an a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

OS X only supports Microsoft Exchange, not Exchange ActiveSync. [ActiveSync is only supported on iOS/Android](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2563324)  This is why Mail will not connect but your iPhone and iPad will.

Comment: Yes, i got that part but I hoped there was some sort of a work around. Thanks for the link! I'm leaving the question open, maybe someone knows of a third-party tool that can fetch the mails/calendar.

Comment: I have looked for several years - I was never able to find one.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of that would solve this issue is if your IT staff were to enable POP/IMAP on the Groupwise Server for email and caldav for the calendar.  Your other option is to run VirtualBox/Parallels/Boot Camp and use native Windows clients.